# Dúvida consumir json com AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

eu criei esse código a nível de teste para tentar consumir um "json" via AJAX. Gostaria que vocês me dissessem onde eu estou errando pôs estou recebendo este erro:

***json.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vagalumewifi.com.br/timeline. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:49844' is therefore not allowed access.***

Segue o meu código abaixo, obrigado desde já!

```
var jsonTeste = function(){
    $(".botao-teste").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "vagalumewifi.com.br/timeline.json",
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            dateType: "json",
            success: function(retorno){
              $.each(retorno.timeline, function(){
                  var conteudo = this;
                  alert(conteudo.content);
              })  
            }
        })
    })
};
$(jsonTeste);
```

Comment: O problema é que voce está fazendo a requisição ajax para outro domínio, voce tem acesso à pagina http://vagalumewifi.com.br/timeline?

Comment: já tentou colocar o `type` como `get`?

Comment: O link é público amigo

Comment: Já coloquei "get","json",jsonp e nada

Comment: Olá Anderson! Marquei a resposta como duplicada de outra. Lá refere o problema que estás a ter, basicamente o outro dominio não permite ligações externas. Tens de usar um proxy (servidor) ou iFrame.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!